# How do I loop through several charges?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have edited this question included a xml with the nodes to be used for the output and also the xslt I am using.

**The output should include the following:**

ChargeNumber

StatuteCode

StatuteCode/@Word

Degree

ChargeOffenseDate

LocationofViolation

Here is what is required:

For each unique ChargeID evaluate the ChargeHistory records.  If, Stage=”Disposition Event” is found verify the number of DispositionEventSequence.  If only “1” populate Charge Information, otherwise use the highest DispositionEventSequence to populate.

If no Stage=”Disposition Event” is found look for Stage=”Case Filing” to populate.  If only “1” populate Charge information, otherwise use the highest Case Filing Filing Sequence to populate.

**XML Code**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:CMCodeQueryHelper="urn:CMCodeQueryHelper" PackageID="IXML Case Notification Test" MessageID="67078058" xmlns="">
    <Case InternalID="1616807927" ID="11747370" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <Charge ID="10547226" PartyID="16580814" CurrSentenceID="155092098" InternalChargeID="1616447618" InternalPartyID="1614482843" xmlns:reslib="urn:reslib">
            <ChargeOffenseDate>03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
            <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="41490828" Stage="Case Filing" FilingSequence="1" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1635954993">
                <ChargeNumber>1</ChargeNumber>
                <ChargeOffenseDate deprecated="true">03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
                <Statute>
                    <StatuteDescription>Traffic Regulations - Failure to obey traffic control device</StatuteDescription>
                    <StatuteCode Word="169064a" InternalCodeID="66247">Traffic Regulations - Failure to obey traffic control device</StatuteCode>
                    <Degree Word="PMD">Petty Misdemeanor</Degree>
                </Statute>
                <Additional>
                    <LocationOfViolation>Hwy 15 &amp; Century Ave</LocationOfViolation>
                </Additional>
            </ChargeHistory>
            <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="41490828" Stage="Case Filing" FilingSequence="2" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1635954993">
                <ChargeNumber>2</ChargeNumber>
                <ChargeOffenseDate deprecated="true">03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
                <Statute>
                    <StatuteDescription>Testing Case Filling 2</StatuteDescription>
                    <StatuteCode Word="169064a" InternalCodeID="66247">Testing Case Filing 2</StatuteCode>
                    <Degree Word="PMD">Petty Misdemeanor</Degree>
                </Statute>
                <Additional>
                    <LocationOfViolation>Hwy 15 &amp; Century Ave</LocationOfViolation>
                </Additional>
            </ChargeHistory>
            <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="41858685" Stage="Disposition Event" DispositionEventSequence="1" CurrentCharge="true" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1636250409">
                <ChargeNumber>10</ChargeNumber>
                <ChargeOffenseDate deprecated="true">03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
                <Statute>
                    <StatuteDescription>Traffic Regulations - Failure to obey traffic control device</StatuteDescription>
                    <StatuteCode Word="169064a" InternalCodeID="66247">Traffic Regulations - Failure to obey traffic control device</StatuteCode>
                    <Degree Word="PMD">Petty Misdemeanor</Degree>
                </Statute>
                <Additional>
                    <LocationOfViolation>Hwy 15 &amp; Century Ave</LocationOfViolation>
                </Additional>
            </ChargeHistory>
            <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="41858685" Stage="Disposition Event" DispositionEventSequence="2" CurrentCharge="true" InternalOffenseHistoryID="1636250409">
                <ChargeNumber>2</ChargeNumber>
                <ChargeOffenseDate deprecated="true">03/26/2014</ChargeOffenseDate>
                <Statute>
                    <StatuteDescription>Testing second disposition number 2</StatuteDescription>
                    <Degree Word="PMD">Petty Misdemeanor</Degree>
                </Statute>
                <Additional>
                    <LocationOfViolation>Hwy 15 &amp; Century Ave</LocationOfViolation>
                </Additional>
            </ChargeHistory>
        </Charge>
    </Case>
</Integration>
```

I need to modify my xslt code but I am not sure how.

**XSLT Code**

```
<xsl:template name="Charge">

        <ext:Charge>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(count(ChargeHistory[@Stage='Disposition Event']))>0">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ChargeHistory[@Stage='Disposition Event']">
                        <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
                        <j:ChargeSequenceID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ChargeNumber"/>
                        </j:ChargeSequenceID>
                        <j:ChargeStatute>
                            <j:StatuteDescriptionText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode"/>
                            </j:StatuteDescriptionText>
                            <j:StatuteText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode/@Word"/>
                            </j:StatuteText>
                        </j:ChargeStatute>
                        <j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Statute/Degree"/>
                        </j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:when test="(count(ChargeHistory[@Stage='Case Filing']))>0">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ChargeHistory[@Stage=Case Filing']">
                        <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending"/>
                        <j:ChargeSequenceID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="ChargeNumber"/>
                        </j:ChargeSequenceID>
                        <j:ChargeStatute>
                            <j:StatuteDescriptionText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode"/>
                            </j:StatuteDescriptionText>
                            <j:StatuteText>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode/@Word"/>
                            </j:StatuteText>
                        </j:ChargeStatute>
                        <j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Statute/Degree"/>
                        </j:ChargeSeverityDescriptionText>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </ext:Charge>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain data from the `ChargeHistory` with the highest `DispositionEventSequence` value, **sort** the `ChargeHistory` nodes by their `DispositionEventSequence` value. Then take the data from the first (or last, depending on the sort order) node of the resulting set.

Here's a minimized example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Integration">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Case/Charge"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Charge">
    <Charge>
        <xsl:for-each select="ChargeHistory[@Stage='Disposition Event']">
            <xsl:sort select="@DispositionEventSequence" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <ChargeNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ChargeNumber"/>
                </ChargeNumber>
                <StatuteCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode"/>
                </StatuteCode>
                <!-- get more data as needed -->
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Charge>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

In response to:

> If, Stage=”Disposition Event” is found verify the number of
>   DispositionEventSequence. If only “1” populate Charge Information,
>   otherwise use the highest DispositionEventSequence to populate.
>
> If no Stage=”Disposition Event” is found look for Stage=”Case Filing”
>   to populate. If only “1” populate Charge information, otherwise use
>   the highest Case Filing Filing Sequence to populate.

I believe this translates to: sort the records by Stage (`Disposition Event` first), then by their respective Sequence number:

```
<xsl:template match="Charge">
    <Charge>
        <xsl:for-each select="ChargeHistory[@Stage='Disposition Event' or @Stage='Case Filing']">
            <xsl:sort select="number(@Stage='Disposition Event')" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@FilingSequence" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="@DispositionEventSequence" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <ChargeNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ChargeNumber"/>
                </ChargeNumber>
                <StatuteCode>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Statute/StatuteCode"/>
                </StatuteCode>
                <!-- get more data as needed -->
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Charge>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The only problem is that when there is more than one charge I am only getting output for the first charge and not for the second. How do I modify the code you provided so that I can loop through all available Charges using **Charge ID**?

Comment: The only problem is that when there is more than one charge I am only getting output for the first charge and not for the second. How do I modify the code you provided so that I can loop through all available Charges using **Charge ID** and get the output for the right Charge?

Comment: "*The only problem is that when there is more than one charge I am only getting output for the first charge and not for the second.*" No, that's not true.

Comment: I think you are right. It seems to work as intended. How do I add a condition to also check..**If Stage=”Disposition Event” is NOT found look for Stage=”Case Filing” to populate.  If only “1” populate Charge information, otherwise use the highest Case Filing Filing Sequence to populate**.

Comment: Sort by Stage first, then by the sequence number/s.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. Do I add the following code? `<xsl:for-each select="/Integration/Case/Charge/ChargeHistory[@Stage='Case Filing']">
<xsl:sort select="@DispositionEventSequence" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
<xsl:if test="position()=1">`

Comment: Should I use count function to check how many Stage=Disposition Events are there and then also count how many Stage=Case Filing are there?

Comment: Please edit your question and post an example of an input that has these nodes.

Comment: I did change my code to sort and it is working. My only question is, my boss want me to use count. What is the advantage of using one over the other? How would I change your code to instead use count?

Comment: "*How would I change your code to instead use count?*"  I don't know.

Comment: Maybe a better question would have been, how would I use count instead of sort?

Comment: I don't know that either.

Comment: I think I will stick with the sort. Thanks for helping and it is working. I will mark your response as answer.